# How to give feedback "not found" when listview field is not match with field in database

Tags: listview, ms-access, vb6

this is the coding for insert data to my listview from textbox "Receivedata"

```
Private Sub AddList_Click()  
Dim i As Long
Dim sLines() As String
Dim sValues() As String
Dim oItem As ListItem

sLines() = Split(receivedata.Text, vbCrLf)
For i = 0 To UBound(sLines)
If sLines(i) > vbNullString Then ' skip for empty line
  sValues() = Split(sLines(i), ".")

  Set oItem = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , sValues(0)) ' number 
  Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(1))         ' Barcode
  Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(2))         ' Quantity
```

and this code to get data from ms access to my listview like this.

```
rs.Filter = "Barcode = '" & sValues(1) & "'"
      Product_Name = rs.Fields!Product_Name
      Price = rs.Fields!Price

  Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , Product_Name)
  Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , Price)
  Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , (Price * sValues(2)))


total = total + (Price * sValues(2))

  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

this is work.

[image]

but if barcode in my listview is not match with barcode in my database, the compiler will getting error.

[image]

how if the barcode from listview not match with database, the Product_name and price is "null" or "not found"?

Comment: the correct way to check that situation is: `If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then` - don't forget to set also both properties `BOFAction` and `EOFAction`of your DataControl to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for `EOF` after filtering the recordset.

```
rs.Filter = "Barcode = '" & sValues(1) & "'"
If rs.EOF Then
    Product_Name = "not found"
    Price = 0
Else
    Product_Name = rs.Fields!Product_Name
    Price = rs.Fields!Price
End If
```